# Configure multiple values for fundingSource in PayPalButtons | react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal

Is there any way to set multiple values for fundingSource prop in PayPalButtons([react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js))
fundingSource prop is a string type and hence we cannot pass an array. I tried below and it is not working.

```
<PayPalButtons
            style={style}
            disabled={false}
            forceReRender={[amount, currency, style]}
            fundingSource={"paypal", "card"}
        />
```

We can implement two PayPalButtons like below. but is there any other better solution?

```
<>
<PayPalButtons
                style={style}
                disabled={false}
                forceReRender={[amount, currency, style]}
                fundingSource={"paypal"}
            />
<PayPalButtons
                style={style}
                disabled={false}
                forceReRender={[amount, currency, style]}
                fundingSource={"card"}
            />
</>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to specify specific funding sources, the solution is indeed to render multiple (standalone) buttons. Make sure there's sufficient margin between them, I've used this CSS to mimic a vertical stack:

```
<style> .paypal-buttons { margin-bottom:8px; } </style>
```

If you only need to disable certain ones from showing up as part of a smart stack, you can use the `disable-funding` parameter in the script provider instead.

Comment: Just be aware that due to caching local to the browser, flipping this value back and forth can cause other buttons to not render in testing. It'll sort itself out in normal use when you're not changing the value across a user's page loads.